# Ruby break line in multiple string interpolation

Tags: ruby

I want to add below 5 strings using the interpolation. Each string should be separated by a new line:

```
ts = (Time.now.getutc.to_f * 1000).to_i.to_s
nonce = SecureRandom.uuid
host = 'example.com'
resource_path = '/v3/workflows/auth_flow/test'
body_hash = { some: 'hash' }.to_s
```

To do so I'm trying to:

```
signature = "#{ts}\n#{nonce}\n#{host}\n#{resource_path}\n#{body_hash}"
```

But I'm not sure this is correct way because what I getting is:

```
2.7.0 :105 > signature
 => "1637625282656\n666256a1-656c-49ed-b816-47211aecb4b4\nexample.com\n/v3/workflows/auth_flow/test\n{:some=>\"hash\"}"
```

Doesn't this just add an extra string "\n" instead of a newline after each string?

Comment: If you just need to join them with a certain character, why not use [#join](https://apidock.com/ruby/Array/join)?

Comment: If I use `signature = [ts, nonce, host, resource_path, body_hash].join("\n")` the result will be the same. Does that mean it should look like this? I'm not sure about it

Comment: When you do string interpolation, each thing interpolated implicitly has `#to_s` called. If you want a different behavior for the string representation of each object, you'll need to do so explicitly.

Comment: This is odd. `\n` should be fine. What are you using to print `signature` to output?

Comment: @DavidJohnSmith It's part of a bigger thing related to creating an HMAC token to authenticate a request. The signature contains the following elements that are each separated by a new line and are in the same order as it is in the question. My idea was to create that string and then encode it by HMAC Sha256.

Comment: This is correct, console display result of `inspect` call on the string. You can see the actual string when you display it with `puts signature`

Comment: `\n` represents a linefeed. For instance, `puts "ab\ncd".size` prints 5. Try the commands `puts "ab\ncd"` and `p "ab\ncd"` to see the effect on formatting. In the latter case, `inspect` is invoked to format the line feed as the characters `\`  and `n`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is correct and this is the expected output. IRB calls `inspect` method on each object it's trying to display as a return value. For string it means wrapping in double quotes and escaping special characters, including "\n". You can "force" it to display the string as is with `puts signature`.

In case of actual `\n` as two character long string, it would read `"\\n"`